# SCSS: code outlying the body

Tags: sass, compass-sass, mixins

This code works:

```
//test.scss
@import "imageColor";

body {
    $sourceFile: resources/icon/mask;
    $targetFile: resources/compass/images/icon; 
    $color: red;    
    @include createMask($sourceFile, $targetPath, $color);                       
}
```

And this code does not working:

```
//test:scss
@import "imageColor";

$sourceFile: resources/icon/mask;
$targetFile: resources/compass/images/icon; 
$color: red;    
$buttonResult: createMask($sourceFile, $targetPath, $color);
```

Do you know why? I need to post this code outlying the body {}.

Comment: What CSS do you expect to compile without some kind of selector?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using SASS Function on an existing Mixin?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15011527/using-sass-function-on-an-existing-mixin)

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing the

```
$buttonResult: createMask($sourceFile, $targetPath, $color);
```

line with

```
body { 
       @include createMask($sourceFile, $targetPath, $color);                    
}
```

I'm afraid you can't skip body{} altogether. You can't apply a style without mentioning a selector

Comment: Perhaps he needs to target a different selector like html or *.

Comment: Could be. I just wrote body because that's what he has written in the first bit of code in the question.